# Excel VBA script to add apostrophe slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that I use to add apostrophe to cells, but I have currently 200000 rows to check and it seems to take considerably long. The code I'm using is the following:

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    myrange = "c21:c200000"
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(myrange)
    If cell.Value <> "" Then cell.Value = "'" & cell.Value 
    Next
```

Any ideas on how to make the code run faster or do you know of any other code that could work better?

Comment: `.NumberFormat = "@"`?

Comment: Use vbNullstring instead of "". It wont fix your code, but it is good practice.

Comment: Also, is there any reason to do this process on the worksheet? Loading your range into an array and then looping over the array is considerably faster.

Comment: Are you trying to use apostrophes to treat the cell values as text? If so, there are simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: Blackhawk, could you please indicate how

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve with the single quote, but generally, you can fill all empty cells by limiting the range and write to all of them at once:

```
Const DefaultString = "'"
Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Set r = ws.Range("A1:A200000")
' Fill last cell to ensure that SpecialCells looks to complete range
If r.Cells(r.Rows.Count, 1) = "" Then r.Cells(r.Rows.Count, 1) = DefaultString
Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
r.Value2 = DefaultString
```

Comment: If it can be reasonably assumed that *'200000 rows'* was an off-the-cuff reference (and they usually are), why not `Set r = ws.Range(ws.cells(21, "C"), ws.cells(rows.count, "C").end(xlup))` ?